# To extract sub-part of string in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, extract

I have log file where each line is showing warning

17>C:\Work\gital\DK\GK\astl/**algorithm.h(1186): warning C4389: '==' : signed/unsigned mismatch** (C:\Ga\gate\source\src\MainSc.cpp)

17>C:\Work\gital\DK\GK\dgfgtl/**string.h(1084): warning C4127: conditional expression is constant** (C:\Ga\gate\source\src\FreeSc.cpp)

**From each line, I want to get the part of string**

algorithm.h(1186): warning C4389: '==' : signed/unsigned mismatch MainSc.cpp

string.h(1084): warning C4127: conditional expression is constant FreeSc.cpp

*If I could get these extracts it would be great.* Basically I have log file with warnings data and I want to extract sub-part from the same.

Answer (score 0):

For the given 2 lines `cut` is the easiest answer. Depending on the other lines, you way want something else:

```
cut -d/ -f2 logfile
grep -Eo "/.*" logfile
sed 's/.*astl.//' logfile
```

Comment: my bad, we may not be having "astl" string always it could be anything